# Extracting titles from PDF files?

Tags: python, pdf

I want to write a script to rename downloaded papers with their titles automatically, I'm wondering if there is any library or tricks i can make use of? The PDFs are all generated by TeX and should have some 'formal' structures.

Comment: Where do you get the PDFs title from? Does that information need to be extracted from the PDFs document properties or from the PDFs contents or are you extracting that information from some other source?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract the title of a PDF document from within a script for renaming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44598758/how-to-extract-the-title-of-a-pdf-document-from-within-a-script-for-renaming) ■ Same question on superuser: [applescript - Automatic PDF renaming based on title - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/269058/automatic-pdf-renaming-based-on-title), , contain tools such as Mendeley or pdftitle.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could try to use [pyPdf](http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/) and [this example](http://blog.isnotworking.com/2006/08/extract-pdf-title-from-all-files-on.html).

**for example:**

```
from pyPdf import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

def get_pdf_title(pdf_file_path):
    with open(pdf_file_path) as f:
        pdf_reader = PdfFileReader(f) 
        return pdf_reader.getDocumentInfo().title

title = get_pdf_title('/home/user/Desktop/my.pdf')
```

Comment: for me `title = untitled`

Comment: Do you want to update the answer to use PyPDF2? Pypdf isn't maintained for a long time now

Answer (score 4):

Assuming all these papers are from arXiv, you could instead extract the arXiv id (I'd guess that searching for "arXiv:" in the PDF's text would consistently reveal the id as the first hit).

Once you have the arXiv reference number (and have done a `pip install arxiv`), you can get the title using

```
paper_ref = '1501.00730'
arxiv.query(id_list=[paper_ref])[0].title
```

Answer (score 2):

I would probably start with perl (seeing as it's always the first thing I reach for).  There are [several modules for handling PDFs](http://search.cpan.org/search?mode=module&query=PDF).  If you have a consistent structure, you could use regex to snag the titles.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using [iText](http://www.lowagie.com/iText/) with [Jython](http://www.jython.org/Project/)